# Can't get test Result with jetpack Compose (always displayed as canceled)

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a simple test with jetpack compose like this

```
@MediumTest
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class LoginScreenTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        composeTestRule.setContent { 
            Text(text = "HEY")
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("HEY").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

But it is always displayed in android studio as canceled although it is succeeded
[image]

Only the logcat can show if there is a failure or not

```
I/TestRunner: run finished: 1 tests, 0 failed, 0 ignored
```

So any idea how to fix this please? Any help will be appreciated

```
Compose version : 1.0.0-alpha11
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same report from android studio as displayed in your screenshot. Actually, for me the it was app that was crashing whenever the test launched the app and I was able to find the crash logs in logcat and used that to resolve it.